# How to reload the page after a Firebase delete request has executed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reload

I have a method that sends a delete request to my Firebase collection. I want the page to reload after the delete request has gone through and the doc is deleted. As it is now, the page reloads immediately and the doc doesn't delete but it works fine if I remove the reload part of the code.

```js
async deletePost() {
  database.collection("posts").where("id", "==", this.id).get().then(data => {
    data.forEach(doc => {
      doc.ref.delete()
    })
  }).then(() => {
    M.toast({
      classes: "toast-alert",
      html: "Post deleted"
    })
  }).then(
    window.location.reload()
  )
}
```

Comment: Try to implement doc.ref.delete().then( window.location.reload())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `delete()` call is asynchronous, so you need for *all* of them to complete. The solution for this is to use `Promise.all` on the return values you get from `delete()`:

```
async deletePost() {
  return database.collection("posts").where("id", "==", this.id).get().then(data => {
    const promises = data.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.delete());
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(() => {
    window.location.reload()
  )
}
```